# How to get multi-data from an API JSON in Solidity Smart Contract?

Tags: json, api, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I have to develop a smart contract that when it's called a method it have to return some data from an [API Json](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=10). I've followed the Chainlink's tutorial for single response at this link: [Single Word Response](https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/single-word-response) and I'm trying to get more data by adding:

```
req.add("path", "0,symbol");
req.add("path", "0,name");
req.add("path", "0,image");
```

but when I call the "requestVolumeData" it doesn't return any value.

This is the full code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {

    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    string public id;

    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event RequestDataJson(bytes32 indexed requestId, string id);

    /**
     * @notice Initialize the link token and target oracle
     *
     * Goerli Testnet details:
     * Link Token: 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB
     * Oracle: 0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7 (Chainlink DevRel)
     * jobId: 7223acbd01654282865b678924126013
     *
     */

    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        setChainlinkToken(0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB);
        setChainlinkOracle(0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7);
        jobId = "7d80a6386ef543a3abb52817f6707e3b";
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10; // 0,1 * 10**18 (Varies by network and job)
    }    

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }

      /**
     * Create a Chainlink request the gas price from Etherscan
     */
    function requestDataJson() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
            jobId,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector
        );
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        // API docs: https://www.casabufalini.it/common/api/metadata.json
        req.add(
            "get",
            "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=10"
        );

        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // [{
        //  "id": "bitcoin",
        //  "symbol": btc",
        // ...
        // },
        //{
        // ...
        // .. }]
        // request.add("path", "0.id"); // Chainlink nodes prior to 1.0.0 support this format
        req.add("path", "0,id"); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format
        req.add("path", "0,symbol");
        req.add("path", "0,name");
        req.add("path", "0,image");
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }

     /**
     * Receive the responses in the form of uint256
     */
    function fulfill(
        bytes32 _requestId,
        string memory _id
    ) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        emit RequestDataJson(_requestId, _id);
        id = _id;
    }

    /**
     * Allow withdraw of Link tokens from the contract
     */
    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me how to get the other variables (data) of the API JSON?

Comment: Did you transfer LINK tokens to the your contract? Consumer contract is expected to call `TransferAndCall` function in Chainlink ERC-677 so your contract needs to maintain a balance of LINK token.

Comment: Yes i did. I wouldn't call the function without do it. @FrankKong

Comment: Instead of using the sample codes in single-word response, can you try the sample codes in multi-variables response [doc](https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/multi-variable-responses)? I guess the way you add information in `path` is not correct.

Comment: @FrankKong I tried but I don't have the right jobs for Goerli (he use Sepolia) and the variables get 0 value. Did you know where I can find the right job for Multi-Variables of Goerli testnet?

Comment: check the address and jobId here. https://docs.chain.link/any-api/testnet-oracles/